# finding a special path string in HTML text in python

Tags: python, regex, expression

I'm trying to extract a path in an HTML file that I read.
In this case the path that I'm looking for is a logo from google's main site.

I'm pretty sure that the regular expression I defined is right, but I guess I'm missing something.

The code is:

```
import re
import urllib
a=urllib.urlopen ('https://www.google.co.il/')
Text = a.read(250)
print Text
print '\n\n'
b= re.search (r'\"\/[a-z0-9 ]*',Text)

print format(b.group(0))
```

The actual text that I want to get is:

**/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png**

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer:

```
import re
import urllib

a=urllib.urlopen ('https://www.google.co.il/')
text = a.read(250)
print text
print '\n\n'
b= re.search (r'\"(\/[a-z0-9_. ]+)+\"',text)


print format(b.group(0))
```

Run gives:

```
>>> python stackoverflow.py
<!doctype html><html dir="rtl" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="iw"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop=



"/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png"
```

Explanation o the regex `\"(\/[a-z0-9_. ]+)+\"` : firstly, in the string name of the picture, you miss `.` and `_`. You need to add these two into the square brackets as well since they appear in the path. `\/[a-z0-9_. ]+` matches a patter with `/` followed by some string wtih length at least 1. `(\/[a-z0-9_. ]+)+` replicates the previous match to allow for multiple matches of paths that have more than 1 folders. Finally, you add the two `"` at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 0):

this can help you:

```
re.search(r'\"\/.+\"',Text).group(0)
```

result:

```
>>> re.search(r'\"\/.+\"',Text).group(0)
'"/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png"'
```